# Looping over a string - Is there a better way?

Tags: c#, for-loop, coding-style

I am passing a String Array to a function with the code below. The strings in the array are the first part of email addresses. I need to add domain.com to the end of each string and a "," between each address. I have working code below, but just wondering if there is a (better/cleaner/efficient) way of doing this?

```
String toAddress = "";
for (int x = 0; x < addresses.Length; x++)
{
    if (x == (addresses.Length-1))
    {
        toAddress += addresses[x] + "@domain.com";
    }
    else
    {
        toAddress += addresses[x] + "@domain.com,";
    }
}
```

Comment: `x` is a very bad variable name there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `Join` and Linq `Select` to solve this

```
string toAddress = string.Join(",", addresses.Select(x => x + "@domain.com"));
```

Comment: (in answer to OP question comment, which seems to have been deleted): x is a parameter in a lambda expression, it's effectively saying perform this operation on each element (in this case append "@domain.com". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: **Select** is used to iterate through each item from an array. x denotes a single element (in your case `addresses[x]`). **+** is used to concatenate address with "domain.com". "," as a first parameter is used as a separator.

Comment: @d219 Thanks for the comment and the link I will read up on it.

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar Thanks, makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

fubo has the ideal and most succinct answer but here is another way to do it as well.

```
string toAddress = null;
addresses.ForEach(x => toAddress += $"{x}@domain.com,");
toAddress = toAddress.Remove(toAddress.Length - 1);
```

Comment: If Fubo has the ideal and most succinct answer (which I agree with as I was going to post my own but it wasn't as good), what's the point in adding the above?

Comment: @d219 It's all about alternative ways, please do not discourage new answerers.

Comment: Additional Linq / C#6 education?

Comment: @m.rogalski - perhaps I should have posted this then, I thought it might have got downvoted: string toAddress = $"{string.Join("@domain.com,", addresses)}@domain.com";

Comment: @d219 You can still post another alternative, SO is all about building a knowledge base on which every valid solution is valued.